# Date not updated with angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date, model

I have an input type date filled up by ng-repeat, i want to be able to change the date value but it is not updated:

View:

```
// displaying the date value
<tr ng-repeat="sf in selectedFacture">
    <td><input type="date" class="dateCom" ng-model= "sf.dateCom | date" value="{{sf.dateCom}}"/></td>
    <td><input type="date" class="dateRec" ng-model= "sf.dateRec | date" value="{{sf.dateRec}}"/></td>
    <td ng-click="updateFacture(sf,id)"> update </td>
</tr>
JS:
//sending the date to server side and update the database
$scope.updateFacture=function(sf,id){
          // getting the changed date
                         var editDateCom = sf.dateCom,
                             editDateRec = sf.dateRec;

            var data = {
                "id":id,
                "editDateCom":editDateCom,
                "editDateRec":editDateRec
            };
            var options = {
            type : "get",
            url : url,
            data: data,
            dataType: 'json',
            async : false,
            cache : false,
            success : function(response,status) {
                 $scope.getClients();

            },
            error:function(request,response,error){
            alert("Erro")
            }
        };
        $.ajax(options);
    }

);
```

Other data updating successfully in the same function but the problem is with the date, it doesn't work at all and the console recorded the following:

**Error: ngModel:datefmt
Model is not a date object**

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why aren't you using Angular's built in `$http`-service? The callbacks from `$.ajax` doesn't trigger Angular's digest cycle and that might cause strange issues. It wont fix this, but it might fix some weird behavior down the road.

Comment: okay thanks but i have to fix this, client is waiting the update! do you have any idea on how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You have used filter inside ng-model directive, which is wrong

`ng-model= "sf.dateCom | date"`

correct usage
`ng-model= "sf.dateCom"`

use the filter inside `{{}}`

Comment: This didn't work with me!
 `<input type="date" class=" dateCom" ng-model= "sf.dateCom" value="{{sf.dateCom | date}}" />`

Comment: @AlyAlAmeen You can't easily format the date in the input field using AngularJS. Formatting using the `date` filter is only visual - it only goes one way. So using the date filter on an input element doesn't make any sense. If you want the date formatted, I suggest you look at some sort of datepicker component.

Comment: i even removed the date format from `ng-model` , but no thing happened, the same error still recorded in the console.
`<input type="date" class=" dateCom" ng-model= "sf.dateCom" value="{{sf.dateCom}}" />`

Comment: use without the expression symbol
 `value="sf.dateCom"`